# How to properly retrieve a products primary and secondary categories using joins and group_concat?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out a query to retrieve list of categories that a particular product is in.

I have a database called products that has three tables called categories, product_to_sec_cat_assoc, and products.

```
+--------------------+ +--------------------+ +--------------------------+
| Products           | | categories         | | product_to_sec_cat_assoc |
+--------------------+ +--------------------+ +--------------------------+
| product_id         | | category_id        | | product_id               |
| pri_category_id    | | category_name      | | category_id              |
| name               | | url_link           | +--------------------------+
+--------------------+ +--------------------+
```

As not all products have secondary category, I am assigning its primary category to the product directly in the product entry.  If they are also in other secondary categories, I use an association table called product_to_sec_cat_assoc to associate the further categories.

I am having trouble writing a query, where I want to create a page that displays all the products in a particular category.  Each product listing also shows the various secondary categories they are in.

My current query is:

```
select t.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name order by pri_category_id, c.category_id) as category_names, 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.url_link) as category_links from products t
left join product_to_sec_category_assoc a using (id)
left join categories c on t.pri_category_id = c.category_id or c.category_id = a.category_id
where t.pri_category_id = 12 
or (a.category_id = 12 and a.id = t.id)
group by t.title
```

For some reason, though, if I add a product to more than one secondary category, when I view the products in one of the secondary categories, it only shows the primary category and the secondary category I am viewing.  On the other hand, If I view the primary category listing, it shows the primary category and ALL its secondary categories.

For example, let's say I have the iPad in the Electronics primary category and in the tablet and mobile secondary categories.  If I visit the Electronics category listing, it shows the iPad in Electronics, Tablet, Mobile.  If I go into the Mobile category it shows it in Electronics, Mobile. If I go into the Tablet category it shows it in the Electronics, Tablet categories.

Another issue I am having is that the query is also not properly ordering the GROUP_CONCAT(category_name) and GROUP_CONCAT(category_link) so that the category_names and their links are in the matching order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is rather tricky considering your design (products having two different relationships to categories). The problem is that in your `WHERE` clause, you are essentially filtering out the rest of the products' categories and only returning the category the user is on and/or its primary category.

Instead, you have to first select the products that have the particular category in either the secondary categories table or in its primary category field (done in `FROM` subselect), **then** join the *result* of that to the secondary categories table - that way you get all of the categories for **only** the products that are in the particular category (whether or not its a primary category):

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(c.category_name, '||', c.url_link) ORDER BY c.category_name) AS categories
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            aa.product_id,
            aa.pri_category_id,
            aa.name
        FROM
            products aa
        LEFT JOIN
            product_to_sec_category_assoc bb ON 
                aa.product_id = bb.product_id
                AND bb.category_id = 12
        WHERE
            aa.pri_category_id = 12
            OR bb.product_id IS NOT NULL
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    product_to_sec_cat_assoc b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    categories c ON 
        a.pri_category_id = c.category_id
        OR b.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY
    a.product_id
ORDER BY
    a.title
```

The two `12`'s represent the current category the user is in.

One thing you have to watch out for is that the `OR` in the second `LEFT JOIN` will always join two rows for each product that has at least one secondary category - one row will always be that product's primary category. So visually in the join, for each secondary category that is listed for a product, you'll have the product's primary category tacked on top of it, resulting in duplication. This is why you have to introduce `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

In the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, I've decided to consolidate the `category_name` and `url_link` fields together, separated by `||`. Depending on what language you're using in your application, you can split the two based on that delimiter. This is better than trying to match up the order in two different columns.

---

Perhaps a better design would be to just have a many-to-many relationship between products and categories, and have a field in your cross-reference table indicating whether the category is primary or not. The schema would look something like:

```
+---------------+ +-------------------+ +----------------+
| products      | | product_cat_assoc | | categories     |
+---------------+ +-------------------+ +----------------+
| product_id    | | product_id        | | category_id    |
| name          | | category_id       | | category_name  |
+---------------+ | is_primary        | | url_link       |
                  +-------------------+ +----------------+
```

Now you would only have to be concerned with retrieving categories based on one relationship instead of two. The `is_primary` field could be a TINYINT(1), containing `0` or `1` to indicate whether it's primary or not. In this design, all products should always have at least one corresponding row in the `product_cat_assoc` table representing the primary category. Additional rows would be secondary categories.

Then to retrieve the list of all categories for products within a particular category, the query would be as simple as:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.category_name, '||', c.url_link) ORDER BY b.is_primary DESC) AS categories
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            aa.product_id, 
            aa.name
        FROM 
            products aa
        INNER JOIN 
            product_cat_assoc bb ON aa.product_id = bb.product_id AND bb.category_id = 12
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    product_cat_assoc b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
INNER JOIN
    categories c ON b.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY
    a.product_id
ORDER BY
    a.name
```

Comment: This was perfect.  I had no idea that what I was trying to do would be so complicated and I never would have figured it out without your help.  I went with the is_primary model and its working great.  Truly appreciate it.